# Write sitemap.xml to java webapp root directory permission denied

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the sitemapgen4j library to build my sitemaps. I'm facing a permission problem while trying to write to my root directory

https://code.google.com/p/sitemapgen4j/

the root context folder (/src/main/webapp)

**Exception**

```
Problem writing sitemap file /sitemap.xml 
java.io.FileNotFoundException
/sitemap.xml (Permission denied)
```

Code

```
File directory = new File("/");
WebSitemapGenerator wsg = new WebSitemapGenerator("http://localhost:8080/app", directory);
```

Does anybody know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write to root directory ('/') which is not writable for the user account you are using to run the sitemapgen4j (i.e. only root user can write to '/'). Change it to any directory where you have write access.

Comment: What's your thought on writing to a temp directory and then storing them on amazons s3 server where I could then just stream the files and avoid storing them on the app server all together?

Comment: That would work or to your home directory.